# How to loop through a JSON array to check for the same value using SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I am wondering how I can loop through a JSON array to check for the same value exists 3 times.

First I am able to access the array like this:

```
select JSON_QUERY(json, '$[0].Data') as DATA
from tickets where id = 12
```

Result: [5,7,1,5,2,8,5,0,3]

I can drill down further to get specific values with:

```
select JSON_VALUE(json, '$[0].Data[0]') as DATA
from tickets where id = 12
```

Result: 5

How can I iterate through the Data array to check that the number 5 exists 3 times within the array? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `JSON_TABLE` if your mysql version support that.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tickets t1 
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
   t1.json,
   '$[0].Data' columns (num varchar(50) path '$')
) t2
WHERE num = '5'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51366780d80173b7ad7f5e9b0ed7b3e0)

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql `json_table` function to convert your array into rows.

```
select t1.Value, count(1) from
       json_table(select JSON_QUERY(json, '$[0].Data') as DATA
                from tickets where id = 12
       ,"$[*]" columns(Value int path "$")) t1
group by t1.Value
```